# Класс не найден, но файл в котором находится класс, подключен

Tags: php

Подключаю файл Реестра (Код. 1) в точке доступа index.php (Код. 2). И дальше я хочу использовать этот класс. Но возникает ошибка: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Registry' not found", хотя файл подключен и успешно выводиться переменная $test (Рис. 1).

Дальше работает автозагрузчик и он подключает файлы таким же способом как и я ранее, и ко всем классам можно обратиться. В чем проблема?

**Код 1**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\core;

$test = 'Lorem Ipsum';

class Registry {
    protected static $registry = [];
    protected static $instance = null;

    protected function __construct() {
        $config = include_once(ROOT . '/config/config.php');
        $components = $config['components'];
        foreach ($components as $component => $namespace) {
            self::$registry[$component] = new $namespace;
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$instance === null) {
            $class = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $class;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function get($key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, self::$registry)) {
            return self::$registry[$key];
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function set($key, $item) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, self::$registry)) {
            self::$registry[$key] = $item;
        }
    }

    public function remove($key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, self::$registry)) {
            unset(self::$registry[$key]);
        }
    }
    private function __clone() { }
    private function __wakeup() { }
}
```

**Код 2**

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
use vendor\core\Router;

$query = rtrim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '/');

define('WWW', __DIR__);
define('CORE', dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/core');
define('ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));
define('LIBS', dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/libs');
define('APP', dirname(__DIR__) . '/app');
define('PUBLIC', dirname(__DIR__) . '/public');
define('LAYOUT', 'default');

include_once('../vendor/libs/functions.php');
include_once(str_replace('\\', '/', ROOT . '/vendor/core/Registry.php'));

echo $test;
Registry::getInstance();

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $file = str_replace('\\', '/', ROOT . '/' . $class . '.php');
    if( is_file($file) ) {
        include_once($file);
    }
});

/*
    Your rools is here
    Example: Router::add('^pages/?(?P<action>[a-z-]+)?$', ['controller' => 'Posts']);
*/

Router::add('^$', ['controller' => 'Main', 'action' => 'index']);
Router::add('^(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)/?(?P<action>[a-z-]+)?$');

Router::dispatch($query);
```

**Рис. 1**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что класс `Registry` в неймспейсе `vendor\core`.

Comment: Помогло, благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Решение: Нужно удалить namespace vendor\core из класса Registry. Вот правильный код:

```
    <?php

class Registry {
    protected static $registry = [];
    protected static $instance = null;

    protected function __construct() {
        $config = include_once(ROOT . '/config/config.php');
        $components = $config['components'];
        foreach ($components as $component => $namespace) {
            self::$registry[$component] = new $namespace;
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$instance === null) {
            $class = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $class;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function get($key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, self::$registry)) {
            return self::$registry[$key];
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function set($key, $item) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, self::$registry)) {
            self::$registry[$key] = $item;
        }
    }

    public function remove($key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, self::$registry)) {
            unset(self::$registry[$key]);
        }
    }
    private function __clone() { }
    private function __wakeup() { }
}
```